# Drupal login error message displayed without using form_set_error()

Tags: drupal

I created a module that adds a field to the user login block form to display errors. I want to display the error in the new field instead of using `form_set_error()`. I am able to see the warning field in the login block. But when I submit with an error it does not display the error.

Code is as follows. I do not understand how to refresh the value of form once it gets an error.

```
function usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['warning'] = array(
    '#value' => t('oops'),
    '#weight' => 11
  );
  $form['#submit'][] = 'usermoved_form_submit_code';
}

function usermoved_form_submit_code($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if (!$user->uid) {
    $form['warning']['value']= "changed to someting";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong: Instead of using `$form['warning']['value']`, it should use `$form['warning']['#value']`. Even doing so, the message (which should be passed to `t()`) is not shown to the users because `$form` is not passed by reference, and it is not the value returned from the form submission handler, which is not expected to return any value.

Form submission handlers are then never called, when a form validation handler raises an error. If you are checking the user ID to see if the user has not been logged-in, then you cannot do it in a form submission handler, as the user not being logged-in means there have been errors during the validation phase, and the form submission handlers are not invoked.

What you can use is a form validation handler.

```
function usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $message = (empty($_SESSION['usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter']) ? t('Initial message') : $_SESSION['usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter']);

  $form['warning'] = array(
    '#value' => $message,
    '#weight' => 11
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = 'usermoved_form_validate_code';
}

function usermoved_form_validate_code($form, &$form_state) {
  if (empty($form_state['uid'])) {
    $_SESSION['usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter'] = t('The error message');
  }
  else {
    unset($_SESSION['usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter']);
  }
}
```

`$form_state['uid']` is a value set from [user_login_authenticate_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7), the second validation handler invoked by Drupal. When it is not set, it means there have been some errors before Drupal tried to authenticate the user, or the user didn't authenticate. The first case can happen when the user is blocked ([user_login_name_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_name_validate/7) verifies that), or the user tried too much times to authenticate (see [user_login_authenticate_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7) which uses [flood_is_allowed()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/flood_is_allowed/7) to verify the user didn't try too much times to authenticate);  the latter case can happen when the user didn't enter the right password. (See [user_login_final_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7).)

As side notes:

- I used `t('Initial message')` as default message, but that could be replaced with `''`, if you don't have any message to show to the users before they log in.
- The user login block is not shown to already logged-in users. `$user->uid` (where `$user` is the global variable) is always 0, when the login block is shown, and when logging-in failed; checking the value of `$user->uid` while showing the login block doesn't make sense.

Comment: i copied the code exactly as you mention. I entered echo command in usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter   and usermoved_form_submit_code . First time load no no value in GLOBAL Array and message. Then i enter wrong id and pw stil no value in $message variable. I found that the submit function is not called. Because i enter the echo statement in this as well.

Comment: When a form validation handler raises an error, the form submission handlers are not invoked; that is what happens when the user enters the wrong username, or the wrong password. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But still one problem is left. First time i submit wrong password and uid it did not show the error. Then second time i enter wrong pw and uid it show the error. Then i login and logout again and try same thing but only second time it show the error. I do not understand the reason

Comment: i modify the code "usermoved_form_validate_code($form, &$form_state) {
print $_SESSION['usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter']; it show the error value but do not display in form. only display it on second time error.

Comment: I pass the form by refence function usermoved_form_validate_code(&$form, &$form_state)  still problem did not resolved

Comment: Please look at the warning field detail from print_r($form) under validate. [warning] => Array([#value] => Initial message [#weight] => 11 [#post] => Array([name] => Username [pass] => usufusuf [op] => [form_build_id] => form-853bdce5871ab772385ebc1dedf93988[form_id] => user_login_block)[#programmed] => [#tree] => [#parents] => Array ([0] => warning) [#array_parents] => Array
([0] => warning)[#processed] =>[#defaults_loaded] => 1 [#sorted] => 1 )...... this value after first submit value field must contain "error" but it contain initial value